# Convert an IntPtr window handle to IWin32Window^

Tags: c++-cli, handle

How do I convert a handle acquired from a form/control's Handle property, to a IWin32Window^ ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Control.FromHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle.aspx)

(That gets you the Control object, which implements the IWin32Window interface.)

Eg.

```
IntPtr myWindowHandle = IntPtr(someVal);
IWin32Window^ w = Control::FromHandle(myWindowHandle);
```

Note that this relies on the handle being "acquired from a form/control's Handle property."  You cannot use this technique with an arbitrary Win32 window handle.

Comment: James, I edited a qualification into your answer because people coming here from a more general search on `IntPtr` and `IWin32Window` might only read the question title and not appreciate the constraint in the question detail.  Hope this is okay.

Comment: No, it's a good edit. You probably saved some hapless future programmer from hours of head-scratching wondering why he can't magically create a Control/IWin32Window object from a raw HWND. :)

Answer (score 28):

There's a simpler method that is supported directly by the .NET framework without having to create your own custom class. You can use this with *any* arbitrary Window handle.

Given **ptrWindowHandle** of type **IntPtr**:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

NativeWindow nativeWindow = new NativeWindow();
nativeWindow.AssignHandle(ptrWindowHandle);
```

**System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow** implements the **IWin32Window** interface.

Comment: You can also just use the static `NativeWindow.FromHandle(ptrWindowHandle);`

Comment: @MattSmith I've found that it has to be assigned. FromHandle doesn't work for me unless AssignHandle was used beforehand. For example this works: `NativeWindow nativeWindow = new NativeWindow(); nativeWindow.AssignHandle(GetConsoleWindow()); box.ShowDialog(NativeWindow.FromHandle(GetConsoleWindow()));` (or even `box.ShowDialog(nativeWindow);`) ... but this one-liner without the assignment doesn't: `box.ShowDialog(NativeWindow.FromHandle(GetConsoleWindow()));`

Answer (score 8):

This appears to be exactly what you are asking for. I've never done it myself, but it appears to be relatively straightforward:

[Creating a IWin32Window from a Win32 Handle](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/03/23/465.aspx)

Good luck!

Comment: Well I was going crazy for a couple hours trying to get the above to work, which it does not, at least not in my case. It actually was setting the *parent* window to my new window, so when my application ended, it also killed the parent application, which was clearly not desired behavior. Anyway, this is the actual correct answer - though I'd encourage you, if you see this, to put the answer *in* the actual answer rather than a link, in case that link dies later. (Though thankfully, it lasted this long!)