# Cross-thread exception when setting WinForms.Form owner - how to do it right?

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

I have a main UI thread which runs the application and creates the main window form (let's call it `W`). I have also a secondary thread that I spin up and which creates a dialog box (let's call it `B`).

I want to set the owner of the dialog `B` to be the main window `W`. The setting of `B`s owner happens on the thread that created `B`. Basically:

```
b.Owner = w;
```

but this throws a cross-thread exception telling me that I am tryng to access the `W` object from the wrong thread.

So I tried to execute the code on the main UI thread, by using a `Control.Invoke` on `W`. But then, I get the same error telling me that I am trying to access `B` from the wrong thread:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'B' accessed from a
  thread other than the thread it was created on.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
```

How am I supposed to do it right?

Comment: Don't use forms on multiple threads.  It will give you more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Did you read this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046245/whats-wrong-with-my-cross-thread-call-in-windows-forms ? If this does not help you, you should post the code which gives you the error.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us which feature(s) of ownership you were hoping to take advantage of (hopefully not all of them), and we could suggest ways to achieve similar effects?

Comment: Thanks to all who posted; I know that I am asking for trouble. I need to run some legacy code on the main UI thread, and I want to have a progress dialog showing while this is happening; and I can't let the main UI thread handle the progress dialog. So I went for a progress dialog managed 100% by another thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bit of a bug in Winforms, Windows actually supports making the owner a window that was created on another thread.  There's a way to disable that check, something you should *never* do.  Except when you have to I suppose:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var t = new Thread(() => {
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            var frm = new Form2();
            frm.Show(this);
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;
            Application.Run(frm);
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }
```

I do *not* know if this is 100% safe, there could be a Winforms interaction that screws things up.  You are in untested waters here, infested with threading sharks.

Comment: Your suggestion is interesting. In my case, I can make sure that the code which shows the dialog won't interfere with the main UI thread. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Have you found out anything further about the safety of the above approach?  I would like to do this (have one form own a form which is bound to a different thread) but see two concerns: (1) Showing a form which is owned by another will call `Owner.AddOwnedForm` which is probably not thread-safe; better to do the action on the owner form's thread; (2) If two forms bound to different threads try to show themselves simultaneously, one might set  `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls=true` between the time the other sets it false and the time it performs the operation that requires it to be false.

Comment: Apparently another solution exists, where you pass the parent's `.Handle` to the thread's procedure as a parameter, and inside the procedure [create a `NativeWindow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10957261/11683) from that handle and pass it to `.Show()`. Then it is not required to switch off the `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`.

Answer (score 3):

`B` needs to be created on the UI thread.

You can still interact with `B` from the secondary thread by using `Control.Invoke`.

Comment: In my case, it won't work for what I intend to do: my `B` window won't update if the main UI thread is blocked doing its work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're actually running two message loops on different threads, then there's no way to do what you're after. If you want `W` to own `B`, you're going to have to create `B` on the main thread and `Invoke` all of your interaction with `B` from the second thread.