# Show Form Always On Top Of Other Form Which is Created In Different Thread

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-thread exception when setting WinForms.Form owner - how to do it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273674/cross-thread-exception-when-setting-winforms-form-owner-how-to-do-it-right)

I'm newbie to C# Windows Forms Application Development.

In my application main form we create new forms in other thread like below.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                PlotForm plotForm = new PlotForm();
                Application.Run(plotForm);
            });
```

I want to display that forms always on top of the main form. There is a topmost property in Forms. If i set it to true they are also  on top of the other forms.

In the internet it is said that solution   is to  set owner property  and when i set this property , i got cross thread operation because forms are created different threads.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                PlotForm plotForm = new PlotForm();
                plotForm.Owner = this;
                Application.Run(plotForm);
            });
```

**Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.**

Do you know a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you need to run in different thread?

Comment: This is the only case I know where the cross-threading check is not accurate.  Windows does in fact support this.  Running a form on a thread-pool thread however is *not* supported, the thread must be an STA apartment.  A plain Thread object and a call to its SetApartmentState method is required.  Don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

For cross thread operations you need to use `Invoke`. The "invoke" call tells the form "Please execute this code in your thread rather than mine."

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                PlotForm plotForm = new PlotForm ();
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {                   
                   plotForm.Owner = a;
                   plotForm.Show();
                });
            });
```