# Windows Dialog Box not getting opened

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, credential-providers

Im trying to open a Dialog box in Windows machine(using windows credential provider), when the user presses a button. i tried the below code but, dialog box is not getting opened. i have a resource "IDD_DIALOG1" and callback method "ChangePasswordProc".

HWND hwndOwner = nullptr;

::DialogBox(HINST_THISDLL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hwndOwner,ChangePasswordProc);

Comment: Are you able to see your dialog if you press `Alt+Tab`? It is possible that the dialog is hidden behind credential provider

Comment: i can't able to see

Comment: Are You trying to raise dialogue from inside of Credential Provider? Inside of which method You are doing it?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at the value returned by the DialogBox call?  Have you verified that IDD_DIALOG1 refers to a valid dialog box resource and that the resources are linked into your project?  Have you looked with Spy++ to see if the window exists but it simply offscreen or missing WS_VISIBLE?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't write in Windows GUI for a looong time, but perhaps try something like this:

```
HWND dialog = ::DialogBox(HINST_THISDLL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hwndOwner,ChangePasswordProc);
ShowWindow(dialog, SW_SHOW);
```

I remember, that creating window does not imply showing it - it must be done explicitly.

Comment: i tried this too                                                                                                   
HWND hwndGoto = NULL;  // Window handle of dialog box 
if (!IsWindow(hwndGoto)) { 
    PrintLn("No previous Window available");
    hwndGoto = CreateDialog(HINST_THISDLL, 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TILE_IMAGE), hwndOwner, nullptr); 
   ShowWindow(hwndGoto, SW_SHOW); 
}

Answer (score 0):

To create any window from inside of `Credential Provider` you must first get parent window handle by calling `OnCreatingWindow` method of `ICredentialProviderCredentialEvents` interface.

```
HRESULT OnCreatingWindow([out] HWND* phwndOwner);
```

Pointer to this interface is supplying to your provider by calling  `Advise` method of its `ICredentialProviderCredential` interface :

```
HRESULT Advise([in] ICredentialProviderCredentialEvents* pcpce);
```

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52083206/3868464).