# How to set a button to open an application on windows login screen

Tags: c++, windows, credential-providers, winlogon, screen-lock

This is my first question.

I would like to know if there is a way to set a button on the login screen to open a custom app.

I have already searched by Microsoft documentation then found about credential provider but I don't want to create an IU login. I just want to open an application like this:

[image]

[image]

[This is what I want to achieve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeY-4hlJ9gs)

If there is something that might help me it will be welcome.

Comment: Looks like you can find a demo version of that software. Use a registry snapshot tool and find out where that program registers itself.

Comment: the website for a demo is down.

Comment: I guess the use the method HRESULT PasswordResetCredential::SetSelected(BOOL* pbAutoLogon)  to launch  the app

Comment: It might not actually be an application, the UI could all be part of the credential provider - that's the way it *ought* to be done, at any rate.  But I believe if you launch an application from a credential provider (via CreateProcess or by any other means) it will be visible to the user.

Comment: In Provider::SetUsageScenario, enumerate your credential under CPUS_LOGON case. 
Increment pdwCount in GetCredentialCount to set number of tiles to display. 
Enumerate the credential in getCredentialAt. What you do in that credential doesn't matter. As @Harry_Johnston said, you can pretty much load any graphical interface (Windows Login screen simply being a desktop particularly locked down to lambda users). Do your stuff in it then call for CredentialsChanged event to get back to Tile selection screen. - Had to pass the details like tile picture load etc... due to comment size restriction.

Comment: Almost everything is set up as you request. I following this https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/aho/2009/11/14/custom-credential-provider-for-password-reset/  I don't know where open the app and hide all the IU. what I need is just click on the tile then open the app.

Comment: I'd do it in Credential::SetSelected as you mentionned. I never worked with a "classic behavior" credential though... so make sure there is no problems with loading your interface BEFORE returning S_OK. Might be completely transparent... specially if your IU hide tiles.

Comment: you can see where I call my app https://github.com/azufre/CredentialProvider/blob/8697c8b1b95f6c43853a85dbf803b6d64dcdbcc4/PasswordResetCredentialProvider/PasswordResetCredential.cpp#L132  it works. but when it is selected the tile and get block the screen after a few minutes it open by itself the app.

Comment: system(start) doesn't pause the current thread that keeps going & returns S_OK. What you wanna do is to not return while your app is running. And even this might not give you the expected result. In the case your credential formally want you to return, you'd have to launch the App thread before the function and use SetEvent/WaitForSingleObject to decide wether or not the UI should be displayed.

Comment: I don't want to display the IU. what method should I use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200078/discussion-between-bob-white-and-kianii).

Comment: What they seem to be doing in the initial example you gave us is just displaying some kind of user interface so that it hides the logon screen. In your case, the program is totally isolated from the credential code.

Comment: Yep I want to get that. I ask for that.

Comment: Using system(start), they probably don't share the same adress space. I don't think there is anything you can do about it. Except inside TestStartApp.exe code. Depends what it is written with.

Comment: yep, I did it. but there is something more to face. I got opened the app but if the screen gets the background lock the app is launched, it's like the event Credential::SetSelected is triggered by default.

Comment: Do we agree that the code given below didn't change. Especially the following : 
Credential::SetSelected --> *pbAutoLogon still set to FALSE
Provider::GetCredentialCount --> *pdwDefault still set on CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_NO_DEFAULT & *pbAutoLogonWithDefault to FALSE
Provider::GetCredentialAt didn't change too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To open a custom app by using credentials provider there are two ways to do it.

1) Launch an app when trigger the event SetSelected from provider credential

```
HRESULT PasswordResetCredential::SetSelected(BOOL* pbAutoLogon)  
{
    *pbAutoLogon = FALSE;  

    system("start C:\\TestStartApp.exe");

    return S_OK;
}
```

It may work fine but when the screen gets the wallpaper lock it will trigger automatically the event SetSelected. so the app will reopen again.

2) Create an CommanLink then launch the app in the event CommandLinkClicked

```
HRESULT PasswordResetCredential::CommandLinkClicked(DWORD dwFieldID)
{

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    if (dwFieldID < ARRAYSIZE(_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors) && (CPFT_COMMAND_LINK == _rgCredProvFieldDescriptors[dwFieldID].cpft)) {
        system("start C:\\TestStartApp.exe");
    }

    return hr;

}
```

both works but it could be a huge risk for our security. majority of developers doesn't recommend to use the credential provider for this way. we are using a fake credential provider to open an app.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a call for expternal process inside of your own credential provider tile you must do this steps:

1. Is call to `ICredentialProviderCredential::Advise` - your provider will receive a pointer to `ICredentialProviderCredentialEvents` interface of `LogonUI`.
2. You call to `ICredentialProviderCredentialEvents::OnCreatingWindow` to obtain a `HWND` for parent window.
3. As you mentioned above you can create a new process inside of handler to call of your providers `ICredentialProviderCredential::SetSelected`.

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55411840/3868464).

Comment: He's not using a Dialog. Not sure he can retrieve the handle.

Comment: The linked post is for example of doing some job inside of Credential Provider.

Comment: My bad, was looking at Diodacus answer