# Display modal on login screen of Credential Provider

Tags: windows, credential-providers

I want to display modal after clicking the logon button like the screen below.
I'm trying to communicate with a server with a timer in modal, is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52089207/3868464).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible
To show a pop-up like that,

1. make a simple standalone C# form program (.exe) to handle that Modal.
2. Later I put the exe file somewhere else inside the pc.
3. Later I use `system((string)L"path-to-exe-file")` command to run that exe file