# Keyboard input doesn't work in WPF window which is launched from the credential provider

Tags: credential-providers

I'm using wpf window to display a modeless dialog inside credential provider.
I am setting the parent for my window using `WindowInteropHelper`.
In most cases everything works fine, but in rare cases the window stops responding to the keyboard. KeyDown events arrive, but no character messages appear.

Probably the reason is that I use Show instead of ShowDialog like described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52089207/22586113.

Has anyone tried using a modeless window from a provider? What are the correct steps to do this?

Show window in most cases works fine, but in very rare cases the window stops responding to the keyboard.

Comment: I’m suggest you use separate thread for your window.

Comment: @Alexander thank you very much for the advice. Does what I wrote in the answer below seem true?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood the advice to make a separate thread for my window, then below is an example of code that does this:

```
using NLog;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfTest
{
    public class LoginUIApplicationInstance: IDisposable
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);


        static protected readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("WpfTest");

        TestWindow? mainWindow;
        Thread uiThread;
        Dispatcher? uiDispatcher;
        TaskCompletionSource windowCreateCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource();

        public LoginUIApplicationInstance(IntPtr ownerHwnd)
        {
            // credential provider thread ID
            var credentialProviderThreadId = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;
            // ID of the parent window thread obtained using OnCreatingWindow
            var parentWindowThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(ownerHwnd, IntPtr.Zero);

            uiThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext());
                uiDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

                mainWindow = new TestWindow();
                var interopHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(mainWindow);
                interopHelper.Owner = ownerHwnd;

                mainWindow.Closed += (sender, e) => mainWindow.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
                windowCreateCompletion.SetResult();
                Dispatcher.Run();
            });

            uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            uiThread.Start();

            logger.Info("Credential Provider threadId: {id1}, Parent window threadId: {id2}, Current window threadId: {id3}",
                credentialProviderThreadId, parentWindowThreadId, uiThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            windowCreateCompletion.Task.ContinueWith((t) => {
                if (mainWindow != null)
                    uiDispatcher?.BeginInvoke(mainWindow.Close);
            });
            uiThread.Join();
        }

        public void Hide()
        {
            windowCreateCompletion.Task.ContinueWith((t) => {
                if (mainWindow != null)
                    uiDispatcher?.BeginInvoke(mainWindow.Hide);
            });
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            windowCreateCompletion.Task.ContinueWith((t) => {
                if (mainWindow != null)
                    uiDispatcher?.BeginInvoke(mainWindow.Show);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The credential provider receives the handle of the parent window (`via OnCreatingWindow`) and creates a window in a new UI thread where it sets the parent via `interopHelper.Owner = ownerHwnd`. Then, when the provider needs to show or hide the window, it calls the appropriate show/hide methods.

The interesting thing is that the parent window is created on a thread different from the one in which the provider methods are executed: `credentialProviderThreadId != parentWindowThreadId`.